# Pulling data from json inside mysql to java

Tags: java, mysql, json

So I have a claim script that I'm trying to put together, that claims the product after purchase. The program is built inside of Java. The problem I'm running into is that there is a custom field they input on their purchase, and the store itself inserts it into a JSON format. So I need to execute a query that pulls the custom field into the WHERE statement, like so :

```
public class StoreClaim implements Runnable {

    public static final String HOST = "104.161.43.58"; // website ip address 
    public static final String USER = "eseezjte_forum";
    public static final String PASS = "Fishsticks123";
    public static final String DATABASE = "eseezjte_forum";

    private Player player;
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement stmt;

    
    public StoreClaim(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    
    

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (!connect(HOST, DATABASE, USER, PASS)) {
                return;
            }

            
            String name = player.getUsername().replace("_", " ");
            ResultSet connect = executeQuery("SELECT ps_claimed, ps_item_id, ps_custom_fields->$.1 AS claimed FROM nexus_purchases WHERE ps_custom_fields->$.1 = '"+name+"' AND ps_claimed='0'");
            while (connect.next()) {
                player.sm("WORKING!");
                return;
                
            }
            

            destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

/**
     *
     * @param host the host ip address or url
     * @param database the name of the database
     * @param user the user attached to the database
     * @param pass the users password
     * @return true if connected
     */
    public boolean connect(String host, String database, String user, String pass) {
        try {
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/"+database, user, pass);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failing connecting to database!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects from the MySQL server and destroy the connection
     * and statement instances
     */
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
                stmt = null;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes an update query on the database
     * @param query
     * @see {@link Statement#executeUpdate}
     */
    public int executeUpdate(String query) {
        try {
            this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement(1005, 1008);
            int results = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            return results;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Executres a query on the database
     * @param query
     * @see {@link Statement#executeQuery(String)}
     * @return the results, never null
     */
    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
        try {
            this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement(1005, 1008);
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            return results;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So i need to insert into this Result Set the JSON I'm trying to pull from.
This is what I'm trying to pull from the database and insert as the name to verify which user bought the product to claim.

[image: Trying to pull "test"]

I get the error :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>$.1 AS claimed FROM nexus_purchases WHERE ps_custom_fields->$.1 = 'quantum' ...' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
    at quantum.site.StoreClaim.executeQuery(StoreClaim.java:139)
    at quantum.site.StoreClaim.run(StoreClaim.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at quantum.site.StoreClaim.run(StoreClaim.java:46)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

which points to :

```
ResultSet connect = executeQuery("SELECT ps_claimed, ps_item_id, ps_custom_fields->$.1 AS claimed FROM nexus_purchases WHERE ps_custom_fields->$.1 = '"+name+"' AND ps_claimed='0'");
```

I need the execute to check the databse, find a row in which the name == the custom field "1": variable, and where claimed == 0, and I will need to pull the ps_item_id from that row to execute inside another file. How do i properly access the array and check if the player name is == to the "1": variable?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Trying to pull test from the json inside the mysql , into the execute query as name in the WHERE statement, as explained above.

Comment: This is not a question. This is a statement.

Comment: although it is quite common in the industry to mock learning developers, you don't need a conjunction to initiate a question, nor a question mark. It is clear that my question is how do I pull the test from the array inside the mysql to label as name inside the execute query as listed above, as stated. As it appears I need to illiterate a conjunction.

Comment: You did not ask any kind of question, you just stated what you want to achieve. We have no clue what the actual problem is or with what concept you are struggling. You provided a sql-statement that does something, probably not to the desired effect, but we do not know where it diverges from the desired effect. So no, there is no clear question.

Comment: The problem was trying to pull the specific array from the mysql, and i even showed where it needed to be inserted into the ResultSet, i showed an example of what I've been trying but didnt work, and even showed what exactly i was trying to pull and where i was trying to put it. Do I need the entire files and entire database structure and server structure to show you where I'm trying to pull? Its pretty clear there is a row im trying to pull from, and initiate that row through a ResultSet and trying to set the array "1": result as name to initiate.

Comment: As I said: It would help if we knew what "did not work" means, i.e. how the current implementation diverges from the desired behaviour.

Comment: it just doesnt read, all i get is : You have an error in your SQL syntax, it doesn't really show any more information except point to the ResultSet, in which means that how I'm trying to get that array is wrong, I've tried a couple different ways but none of them seemed to work or provide information, all I'm getting is error.

Comment: Please [edit] the question, add the full stack trace and highlight the line of code throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple different ways, I found through JSON object how to parse the data. I had to initiate a first ResultSet, and than from that result set, pull the custom_field and than pull that into a JSON Object, parse the "1" to a string, and than use another ResultSet with that string to get that row

```
String name = player.getUsername().replace("_", " ");
ResultSet connect = executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nexus_purchases WHERE ps_claimed='0'");
            
while (connect.next()) {
    String str = connect.getString("ps_custom_fields");
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
    String n = obj.getString("1");
    
    ResultSet check = executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nexus_purchases WHERE '"+n+"' = '"+name+"' AND ps_claimed='0'");
    while (check.next()) {
        player.sm("WORKING!");
        return;
    }
}
```